# Flutter - How can I redirect the screen if the json response is null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code I want to redirect the screen in login page if the result is null,
the current user will match in my database.

My logic is if Firebase current user email is equal to email from local data render the results IF no match it will redirect to login screen.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum(String email) async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    'http://localhost/devph.io/api/student_auth/?student=${email}'));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

  //redirect the screen in login page if the result is null

} else {
  
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}}
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply navigate to the new screen with the replacement method so that the user cannot go back to the previous screen.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum(String email) async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    'http://localhost/devph.io/api/student_auth/?student=${email}'));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (data["studentEmail"] == "") {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()));
  }
  return Album.fromJson(data);

  //redirect the screen in login page if the result is null

} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer. Also, can you post a sample of the JSON when there is no match? It will then be easier to debug.

Comment: Please do a `print(response.body);` so that it helps us know what the content is

Comment: still doesn't redirect bro..

Comment: I have edited my answer to handle your API. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks, you can upvote and accept my answer as a token of appreciation and for others to find the solution.

Comment: My reputation to cast a vote still not enough bro, but thank you so much I will upvote soon.

Answer (score 0):

My API

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `student` WHERE `student_email` = '$email' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

$json = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $theuser = array(
                        'id' => $row['id'],
                        'studentEmail' => $row['student_email'],
                );
                array_push($json, $theuser);
        }
} else {
        $theuser = array(
                'id' => 0,
                'studentEmail' => '',
                
        );
}


header('Content-type: application/json');
$jsonstring = json_encode($theuser, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $jsonstring;

$connect->close();
```

Comment: Please do a `print(response.body);` in your fetch API code in dart so that it helps us know what the content is

Comment: if the user matched in my database flutter: User granted permission: AuthorizationStatus.authorized flutter: {"id":1,"studentEmail":"istran.net@gmail.com"

Comment: if no match 'flutter: User granted permission: AuthorizationStatus.authorized flutter: {"id":0,"studentEmail":""}'